# imgur malformed auth header

Tags: node.js, imgur

I am using "request" trying this example

```
const request = require('request');
request(
  {
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/hot/top/day/0',
    headers: {
      Authorization: { 'Client-ID': '04e2c49522b2562' },
    },
  },
  (e, r, body) => {
    console.log(body);
  },
);
```

receiving this error:

```
"data":{"error":"Malformed auth header","request":"\/3\/gallery\/hot\/top\/day\/0","method":"GET"},"success":false,"status":403}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the Authorization header as an object, try setting it as a string:

```
Authorization: 'Client-ID 04e2c49522b2562',
```

For further details, see [Custom HTTP Headers](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers).